# Spring mock performing post method and Controller redirection

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, testing, mocking

My test:

```
@Test
public void shouldAddCompany() throws Exception {
    Company company = new Company("companyName", new Address());

Mockito.doReturn(company).when(companyServiceMock).save(any(Company.class));

    mockMvc.perform(post("/companies")
            .param("name", "companyName"))
            .andExpect(model().attribute("company",
                    hasProperty("name", is("companyName"))));
}
```

My controller:

```
@PostMapping("/companies")
public String displayCompaniesPost(@ModelAttribute Company company) {
    companyService.save(company);
    return "redirect:/companies";
}
```

There is an error:

```
 java.lang.AssertionError: Model attribute 'company'
 Expected: hasProperty("name", is "companyName")
 but: was null
```

it's because redirection and 302 status. When I change return in PostMapping to

```
return "companies";
```

the test passes, but I need this redirection. How can i fix that?

Comment: When you redirect there is no model as the model will be destroyed due to the redirection...

Comment: Yes, and the question is if there is any option to do this test? For example to check model attribute before redirection?

Comment: No there isn't. As you get only the redirect (and that is what you should check, not the result of the redirect).

Comment: But then I will check only redirection and not passed attributes.

Comment: And why would you want to test the passed attributes? Do you want to test the spring framework (that is basically what you do).

Comment: So how could I test adding company without database? Should I create second database, to test?

Comment: You weren't even testing that... Although you might have thought you were testing that. You only tested the binding of Spring. If you want to verify the save call just use `Mockito` for that.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I can call save with Mockito, but it will create a company in my database. I think it shouldn't be created when I run only test. And if i mock the save method to return the same instance of company, nothing will be tested, right?

Comment: Why not you are testing the call to save, however imho that is pretty useless test. Why not just make this an integration test (using H2) make the test `@Transactional` and after issuing the request (check if a 302 is returned) query the database to see if a record is in there. That is how you should test this.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your help.